# Mention who wrote the question on the 10k flag page to better suss out non-answers

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, not-an-answer

When going through the 10k+ flag list, I have a recurring nag: it's inconvenient to find when the question asker is trying to clarify his or her question with what they did so far, and when an answerer just provides a bad answer.

> [image: Example]

Take the above example: it's flagged as "not an answer", but reading it by itself, it's *vaguely* an answer, just not a very good one.

However, due to the level of tangential information, it sounds like someone trying to clarify what they've tried so far, not provide a solution (e.g., "How do I effectively level archery? I've tried mammoths, but is there a better way? This is my equipment.")

But I have no way to tell that quickly because the asker is missing from the flag preview. I have to click through to the question and confirm that no, it's just a bad answer, not the OP leaving an edit as a new answer.

Would it be possible to get the user card added for both parties—the asker and the answerer—on answer flags?

Comment: You're assuming that the OP manages to use the same user name twice. Many times they don't.

Comment: There is a Community raised flag for self answers - but I don't know the rules for it being triggered. I've seen it on DIY once.

Comment: @DanielBeck True, but in my experience, that generally happens with unregistered users, and most of the time, they use the same IP address, which means the gravatars would match.

Comment: Would be useful in `/review` too IMO, for the same type of reasons.